# jquery.validate.js email validation with domain suffix required

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery.validate.js by Jörn Zaefferer.

All validation is set up perfectly with the following code:

```
$("#homeForm").validate({
    rules: {
          email: {
                   required: true,
                   email: true                             
          },
          mobile:{
                  required:true,
                  minlength:11,
                  maxlength:11,
          }
    },
 });
```

My problem is that the default email validation will allow the user to leave out the domain suffix, for example test@test is validated successfully...

I would like my email validation to require the user to include the domain suffix of the email they input (.com, .co.uk ETC)

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Many thanks in advance...

Comment: I use that script, it doesn't let me typ `test@test`.

Comment: @Barmar http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qvm047hw/1/ - what is the version you are using? even in 1.13.0 the same error is there - [1.13.0](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qvm047hw/2/)

Comment: My application uses 1.10.0, maybe it changed since then?

Comment: I am using version v1.13.1

Comment: Looks like it changed in 1.11.0. The comment in the code says if you have a problem with the current implementation, report a bug against the spec at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#e-mail-state-(type=email)

Comment: There's nothing that prevents the operator of a top-level domain from providing mail service, so `user@uk` would be a valid email if the UK government decided to accept mail there.

Answer (score -2):

So I seem to have found a solution with a little digging through the .js file:

I changed the default email rule from:

```
        email: function(a, b) {
            return this.optional(b) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test(a)
        },
```

to:

```
        email: function(a, b) {
            return this.optional(b) || /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/.test(a)
        },
```

It now works perfectly, bit of strange bug but I hope this helps others who found the same problem

Comment: It's not a bug, it was intentional, to match the HTML5 specification.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. We still develop for non HTML5 browsers...

Comment: He's making his validation compatible with the validation in HTML5.

Comment: And for dev's who still need to cater for non HTMl5?

Comment: It doesn't matter. All he did was use the HTML5 specification to determine what the pattern is for a valid email. That way his validation will be consistent with HTML5 browsers.

Comment: He's not using HTML5, he's just copying its rule.

Comment: You should not be tampering with the core files.  You should have just over-ridden this method with your own using the `addMethod` method.